# Join same table in SQL with different rows having a common link into a single row for that particular link/attribute?

Tags: sql, sql-server

The query that I am using is

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE(tagName nvarchar(256), vvalue Float, lineName nvarchar(10), area nvarchar (8), areaDesc nvarchar(8), euKey int, unit nvarchar (32)) 
DECLARE @finalTable TABLE(tagNameF nvarchar(256), areaF nvarchar (8), areaDescF nvarchar(8), lineNameF nvarchar(10), levelF Float, unitLevelF nvarchar (32), temprF float, unitemprF nvarchar (32)  ) 
INSERT @table1
(
    tagName,
    vvalue,
    lineName,
    area,
    areaDesc,
    euKey,
    unit
)
VALUES
('T1S02C01TT01.PV', '3.99848079681396', 'T1S02C01', 'T1S02',    Null,   '52',   '°C'), ('T1S02C01LT01.PV',  '3956.4545',    'T1S02C01', 'T1S02',    Null,   '34',   'kg'),  
('J1S02C01TT01.PV', '5.99848',  'J1S02C01', 'J1S02',    Null,   '52',   '°C'), ('J1S02C01LT01.PV',  '59984.78778',  'J1S02C01', 'J1S02',    Null,   '32',   '°Ltr'),
('N1N03C01LT01.PV', '35678.99848',  'N1N03C01', 'N1N03',    Null,   '34',   'Kg')

UPDATE @table1
SET

    lineName = SUBSTRING(tagName,1,8),
    area = SUBSTRING(tagName, 1,5)
    FROM @table1    

UPDATE @table1
SET
areaDesc =  CASE    
    
    WHEN    area = 'T1S02' then 'LCT'
    WHEN    area = 'J1S02' then 'ZCT'
    WHEN    area = 'N1N03' then 'Bulk'
    END 
    FROM @table1
    SELECT * FROM @table1 

    Insert into @finalTable 
SELECT  
         tr2.tagName as tagNameF
        ,tr2.area AS  areaF
        ,tr2.areaDesc AS areaDescF
        ,tr2.lineName As lineNameF
        ,tr2.vvalue AS  levelF 
        ,tr2.unit AS    unitLevelF
        ,tr3.vvalue AS temprF
        ,tr3.unit   AS  unitTemprF
          
FROM @table1 tr2
INNER JOIN  @table1 tr3 ON tr2.lineName = tr3.lineName  AND tr2.tagName <> tr3.tagName 
SELECT * FROM @finalTable 
order by lineNameF
```

table1 is a sample table (created via query).

finalTable is the end result of the query in a format that is desired.
The problem is that in finalTable row 1 and 3 are wrong and row 5 (from table 1 is missing).

If I use left join, then, row 5 is appearing in the finalTable.
Still, rows 1 and 3 are not required.

The purpose is to join in a way that values from 'vvalue' having unit of 'kg' and 'Ltr' (from table1) should come in column 'levelF and 'unitlevelF' and vice versa. The result should be like EndTable:

[EndTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wx4i.png)

Can you please guide?

[image: Table1]

[image: finalTable]

Comment: Please spend some time and create your example environment here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019

Comment: Hi, you already mention that. 1. Please remove the pictures and give us tables in a form of create table statements. 2. Give some example data if it is important. 3 Describe more what you want to do. 4. Read and do what I have asked from my comment number 1.

Comment: @SohaibKhalid if you provide sample data, then you'll get a tested solution.  If no sample data, then it's assumed you just want a "best guess" effort

Comment: You are showing the desired result in the image linked to by "Final version". And this result is empty (i.e. it contains no rows). The result you are getting with your query is not empty. If you don't want any rows, just add `WHERE 1 = 2` to your query.

Comment: In my sample table I have the data for level and temperature. For example (from sample table) consider row 32 and row 35 ( having linename2 and area2 common. I want to convert these two rows into a single one in a format ( as shown in my final version). The query that I am using is doing that, but it also giving me another row   ( see rows 1 and 2 from table 3, where row 2 is not desirable)

Comment: I will share sample data and complete query

Comment: @SohaibKhalid please when you do share that data, add it in your question with edit option...

Comment: I have edited the question with sample data.

Comment: Hi @SohaibKhalid great Job, just little bit mote info and the question is perfect. Please try to write(like you have written your code) what is your expected result.

Comment: @VBoka Hi, I have attached my desired result 'Endtable'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it very hard to understand what you are after. From the images it looks like you have a key/value table and you want to select the data so that you show two attributes side by side. The first attribute is either volume or weight (whatever of the two applies) and the second is the temperature. The temperature is optional.

For a key/value table there are uncommonly many columns in the table, however. This means that either your database is not properly normalized or the key is a composite key.

Let's assume the latter (although this is *very* unlikely and you may consider changing your data model). `tagname` + `linename` + `area` + `areadesc` are the key for something, a product for instance. And you want one result row for each such product. A unit is identified by the combination of `eukey` + `unit` where you are looking for 52/'°C' and 34/'kg' and 32/'°Ltr'. Your database ensures somehow that a product can only either have 34/'kg' or 32/'°Ltr'.

The typical way to query key/value tables is by conditional aggregation:

```
select
  tagname, linename, area, areadesc,
  max(case when eukey in (32,34) then vvalue end) as levelf,
  max(case when eukey in (32,34) then unit end) as unitlevelf,
  max(case when eukey = 52 then vvalue end) as tempf,
  max(case when eukey = 52 then unit end) as unittempf
from mytable
where (eukey = 32 and unit = '°Ltr')
   or (eukey = 34 and unit = 'kg')
   or (eukey = 52 and unit = '°C')
group by tagname, linename, area, areadesc
order by tagname, linename, area, areadesc;
```

You may have to adapt this to your needs.

Comment: hi, in 'endtable' (as attached in question), if tagname column is optional or not needed, can rest of the table be achieved ?

Comment: The query will give you rows with ltr/kg and/or °C, but not rows lacking both ltr/kg and °C. If you want to allow for such rows where both units are null, you should remove the where clause.

Comment: It seems that a 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT eukey + '#' + unit) = 3 
is missing....

Comment: @SQLpro: I don't think so. There is not a single element in the sample that has all three attributes, so no rows would be returned. And it seems the OP *wants* to include elements lacking one (or even both?) unit groups.